# How to remotely access a Windows network share?

Tags: networking, ftp, network-shares, smb

I have a Windows (10 Pro, if that matters) machine that has a network share. It (the network share) can be accessed over LAN. However, when I am out, I need a way to access the network share over WAN.

I have ports open for FTP and SMB, have created an FTP server, a fixed internal IP allocation, memorized public IP address, so, everything I need to know.

How do I map an network share over WAN? Ideally, a method that works for both Windows and Linux.

For specifics, do I "Add network location" or "Map network drive"? And, when I need to type the public IP and port, please separate with a ':'.

Comment: Typically you need a VPN connection to get access to the remote site. I have been sharing remote drives for many years this way. No issue. So that is what I suggest to you

Comment: FTP and SMB out.to the Internet.... you’ll get hacked .   Still, it’s map network drive to get to a file share on windows.

Comment: Your logic behind no bandwidth for a VPN is flawed. A VPN only has a very small overhead on top if raw traffic - and often the savings by turning compression on on it give you a net game. Also, a VPN can be used to route only traffic for the given network, it does not need to handle all traffic.

Comment: Simplest way would put the server on a vpn and connect to the vpn remotely, this would make the share accessible, allowing you to access the server.  **This is how you would access the server from a WAN.  There really isn’t another secure option.**

Comment: Even over VPN, as I DID get the VPN to work, I still have problems accessing the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it, provided you can access your router's management interface and open port 3389 (that's the one RDP uses) while you're at home. Associate said port to the private IP address of the machine where the shared folder is (*unless* it's a NAS), and voilà.

I concur with the security risks FTP poses, as it's NOT SECURE AT ALL, even over your own LAN, let alone when accessed from the outside.

Comment: I am confused. 3389 is the port for RDP. I have my RDP port opened and I can access my machine from outside the LAN, but I don't understand how I could map a shared folder this way. I CAN map a drive to grab some small files, but the highest transfer speed I can get is 3 KB/s.

Comment: Several conditions have to be met: the machine your shared folder(s) is on must be running at all times, at least when you want to access the shared folder(s). Then, once connected to that machine over your LAN, you can pin the shared folder(s) to your Quick Access list on the PC you'll be travelling with, on the left pane of any Windows Explorer window. Lastly, you must make sure there's no cap in terms of transfer rate, but remember that most domestic Internet "boxes" are limited in upload speed, unless you have fiber optics Internet at home.

Comment: Please don't even think about opening RDP for external access. That is how at least one known worm can be used to subvert your target machine